# FormData Not Getting Any Response

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

Before, I managed to insert an image file inside a file directory using FormData. But now, the FormData, which I am trying to use now for updating a wrong image, is returning an empty data even though I am passing the correct parameters/payload, which is the file that is an `object`. I tried using FormData.set for updating, and even experimenting on the forEach a bit, but none of them worked for me. In Quasar (which is like Bootstrap for Javascript), we get the `rows` for each data so we can update a row of data. Should I get the row for the image *before* the FormData finally gets a response?

Frontend

```
<template>
<div>
<q-table
          :filter="filter"
          title="Test Section"
          :data="dtdata"
          :columns="columns"
          row-key="TestId"
        >
          <q-tr slot="body" slot-scope="props" :props="props" class="cursor-pointer">
            <q-td v-for="col in props.cols" :key="col.name" :props="props">
              {{
              col.value
              }}
            </q-td>

            <q-td class="q-gutter-md">
              <q-btn label="Edit" color="primary" @click.native="gatherData(props.row)" />
              <q-btn label="Delete" color="red" @click.native="activateDel(props.row)" />
              <q-btn label="Change Picture" color="green" @click.native="changeThisPic(props.row)" />
            </q-td>
          </q-tr>
        </q-table>
</div>
</template>
<script>
methods: {
 changeThisPic(row) {
      this.editPic = true;
      this.editData.testId = row.testId;
      this.editData.testItemId = row.testItemId;
    },
sendPicForUpdate() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch("UPDATE_PIC", {
          testId: this.editData.testId,
          uploadFile: this.editData.uploadFile,
          testItemId: this.editData.testItemId
        })
}
</script>

export default function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    mutations: {
       UPDATE_PIC ({ commit }, payload) {
        const formData2 = new FormData()
        Object.entries(payload).forEach(([key, val]) => {
          formData2.append(key, val)
        })

        axios
          .put('http://localhost/MyComposer/', formData2, {
            params: {
              updateId: 2,
              testId: payload.testId,
              testItemId: payload.testItemId
            }
          })
          .then(response => {
            alert(response.data)
            console.log(response)
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      }
},
```

Backend

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['updateId']) && $_GET['updateId'] == 1) {

            $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $decoded = json_decode($data);
            $testId = $decoded->{'testId'};
            $sub = $decoded->{'subject'};
            $question = $decoded->{'question'};
            $answer = $decoded->{'answer'};
            $testItem = $decoded->{'testItemId'};

            $db->where('TestItemId', $testItem);
            $arrayDir = array('FileLocation');
            $uploaddir = $db->get('teachertest', null, $arrayDir);
            $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES['uploadFile']['name'];
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadFile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
                echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
            } else {
                echo "Upload failed";
            }


            if (!empty($sub)) {

                $sdata = array(
                    'SubjectId' => $sub,
                );

                $db->where('TestId', $testId);
                $newsub = $db->update('teachertest', $sdata);
                if ($newsub) {
                    echo "Subject was changed and";
                }

                $tdata = array(
                    'Question' => $question,
                    'Answer' => $answer,
                );

                $db->where('TestId', $testId);
                $newdb = $db->update('testdetails', $tdata);
                if ($newdb) {
                    echo "Test item details were updated!";
                }
            } 
?>
```

Comment: There's only variable definitions in the example code, are you putting anything into output buffer in PHP?.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I wanted to post a summary of my problem. And even with an output buffer, I still won't get any data because the frontend is not sending any.

Comment: Is your server supporting put, maybe you'd need `axios.post` instead ..? And you're reading `$_GET` while the request was `PUT` ...

Comment: Yes, but I'm curious. Does a different method work on a different Axios HTTP call? Like UPDATE SET on Axios.POST?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Axios, but an [Axios tutorial](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/put) says: "_make a PUT request with ... axios.put() function_", and in the [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-method-aliases) they've listed the method aliases ...

Comment: I see. But is my formula with ForEach correct? It worked in my first attempt in using it. But now, it isn't. I'll edit my question for you guys to see more details about my work.